# How to create an awesome bitmap animation on Android

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I'm a beginner at this, so bear with me.

I have a bitmap image, and I want to animate it **programmatically**.

I want to have the animation of the logo in the video "Indie Nation"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRU2rU2k_NI

Skip to like 0:20 to see.

Anyways, here's what I understand that I have to do. Correct me if I am wrong.

1. Apply scaling for zooming in and out
2. Apply transformations for slightly moving it around

I plan to make an object, have a

```
 public void draw(Canvas canvas)
```

method that will play around with the bitmap.

Also, do I need to use a Matrix, or is it sufficient to modify the canvas directly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Apply scaling for zooming in and out
> 2. Apply transformations for slightly moving it around

Yes, your understanding is correct.

You can use matrix to achieve the expected result as shown below.

```
public class LogoView extends View {
    public LogoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LogoView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LogoView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        logoLeft = -logo.getWidth() >> 1;
        logTop = -logo.getHeight() >> 1;
        matrix = new Matrix();
    }

    private Bitmap logo;
    private Matrix matrix;
    private float logoLeft, logTop;

    private float SCALE_FACTOR = 0.07f;
    private float TRANSLATE_FACTOR = 0.03f;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.setTranslate(getWidth() >> 1, getHeight() >> 1);
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        float scaleFactor = (float) (Math.random() * SCALE_FACTOR) + 1.f;
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        float dx = (float) ((Math.random() - 0.5) * TRANSLATE_FACTOR) * logo.getWidth();
        float dy = (float) ((Math.random() - 0.5) * TRANSLATE_FACTOR) * logo.getHeight();
        canvas.translate(dx, dy);
        canvas.drawBitmap(logo, logoLeft, logTop, null);
        postInvalidateDelayed(150);
    }
}
```